# What is the cause to get Multiple annotations found in dispatcher servlet

Tags: spring

I am working on spring 4.0. I have configured a dispatcher servlet where i have used some xml namespace. its working fine but shows below error.

Error details:

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - Referenced file contains errors (http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd). For more information, right click on the message in the Problems View and select "Show 
     Details..."
    - Referenced file contains errors (http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd). For more information, right click on the message in the Problems View and select "Show 
     Details..."
```

My Code:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd">
```

What is the cause of this error and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

I have resolved it by removing

http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd from schema location.

my corrected code is:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd">
```